# Self-crossing/intersecting polygon in QGIS that tools identifies them as valid

Tags: qgis, polygon, geometry, select, self-intersection

I am using QGIS 3.14 long term version. I need to identify these polygons that are self-crossing.

[image]

Here are the tools I have tried

1. SAGA's "Polygon self-intersect";
2. check validity from vector geometry menu
3. `not is_valid($geometry)` within the "Select by expression" tool
4. using this script:

```py
layer = iface.activeLayer()

feats = layer.getFeatures()
selection = [f.id() for f in feats if any(['intersect' in e.what() for e in f.geometry().validateGeometry()])]
layer.select(selection)
```

All the results are similar to the picture below, the algorithms classified this messy polygon as valid.

[image]

[Here is the link](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1x4sbV0jROgnghLnXJiN9kK_zI94Go_AC/view?usp=sharing) to the part of the shp containing this ugly guy.

Comment: I am using QGIS 3.14 long term version

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that your polygons are multipolygons. So your problematic polygon in fact consists of 139 separate parts - each of them valid ones. That's why the multipart polygon is not recognized as invalid.

Use Select by expression with  `num_geometries( $geometry)>1` to select all polygons that consist of more than one part.

Alternatively, you could use [Topology Checker](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/plugins/core_plugins/plugins_topology_checker.html) to identify multipart geometries.

[image]

Comment: Tks, but it didn't help because I selected many polygons that are ok, mixed with the ugly ones.